# How to interpret undefined points in functions

Tags: continuity, physics, classical-mechanics

Suppose we have the following equation that is not defined if
$g=0, d=0$ or the expression under the radical is negative:
$$
y = \arctan \left( \frac{v^2 \pm \sqrt{v^4 - 2gv^2h-g^2d^2}}{gd}\right)
$$

But its actually angles need for a cannon with speed $v$ to shoot a $(d,h)$ point in an environment with gravitational acceleration of g.

Couldn't load the picture ($h$ is height, $d$ is distance)

1. if $d=0$, the point is over the cannon and it should give 90 degrees if v is enough.
2. if $g=0$, the the path would be a straight line so should give us the following : $\arctan (h/d)$ and not any other angle because only one line passes two points
3. under radical is a bit tricky but i guess it limits the $v$ to a range that it it can be actually possible to hit the point, if $v$ is small enough it will hit the ground or go below its height before reaching it. And may be some other combination of $\{v,g,h,d\}$?

And other situations...

My question is:

> I've found these out by its physical interpretations instead of math itself and i believe math is really really more powerful than that
>   How should i find these with math only and for other equations?

Comment: You probably want to consider the limit of $y$ as $g \to 0$ or as $d \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$\text{atan2}(x,y)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), that as two varible function can carry the sign of its arguments that are lost in calculations with $\arctan(y/x)$. Division by zero is not a problem neither. Anyway, we can do the same using limits, as suggested by gt6989b.

$y = \text{atan2} \left(v^2 \pm \sqrt{v^4 - 2gv^2h-g^2d^2},gd\right)$

1. $d=0$. There are two cases:

   First, $y_+=\text{atan2}\left(v^2+\sqrt{v^4 - 2gv^2h},0\right)=\pi/2$ and for the max heigh, because $v^2\sqrt{v^2-2gh}$ must be real: $v^2\geq2gh\implies h\leq v^2/2g$, as expected.

   Second, $y_-=\text{atan2}\left(v^2-\sqrt{v^4 - 2gv^2h},0\right)$ with $h\leq v^2/2g$ as before, but $y_-=\pi/2$ if $0\leq h\leq v^2/2g$ and $y_-=-\pi/2$ if $h\lt0$

In this situation, $d=0$, we have two angles to pass by some position $(0,h)$ as we have in the general case ($d\neq0\;;h\neq0$), simply, for $h\geq0$ they both coincide.

2. $g=0$. Two cases too: $y=\text{atan2}\left(v^2+v^2,0\right)=\pi/2$ for every value of $h$ and $d$!! and $y=\text{atan2}(0,0)$ that it's not defined, so we cannot avoid taking limits explicitly:

$$y_g=\lim_{g\to0}\arctan \left(\dfrac{v^2-\sqrt{v^4 - g(2v^2h+gd^2)}}{gd}\right)=$$

$$=\lim_{g\to0}\arctan \left(\dfrac{v^4-v^4+g(2v^2h+gd^2)}{gd(v^2+\sqrt{v^4 - g(2v^2h+gd^2)})}\right)=$$

$$=\lim_{g\to0}\arctan \left(\dfrac{2v^2h+gd^2}{d(v^2+\sqrt{v^4 - g(2v^2h+gd^2)})}\right)=$$

$$=\arctan(h/d)$$

As you expected. The weird solution can be understood if we consider that it is a limiting case: we have two paths that can reach a point $(d,h)$. Now, as the gravity faints, one of the paths straighten, but the other needs more and more time to let the gravity to act and make the, say, returning trip. At the end, with $g$ effectively zero, no return is possible and this simply means that the gravity is essential to have two paths!!

3. The general case depends on the radicand being real, so is, $v^4 - 2gv^2h-g^2d^2\geq0$. You are talking about the restrictions $v$ has to have. So, solving for $v^2$:

$v^2\geq gh\pm\sqrt{g^2h^2+g^2d^2}=g(h\pm\sqrt{h^2+d^2})$, dropping the solution with the minus sign as the result is unphysical.

Comment: Why are there limits? While the exact point is well defined in physical model?

Comment: Case 2. is not well treated. I fix this. Anyway, implicitly or explicitly, there are limits because the problem you posed degenerates for certain values. e.g. with $d=0$ we have two paths superimposed, a degenerate situation, when on the contrary, with $d\neq0$, we have two welll separated paths. And worse for $g=0$ as you can check in the edit.

Comment: Intuitively: we tend to think about the setup as taking some orientation for the cannon and then watch what happens with the shell, what points wil it reach. But the problem you posed is asking the reverse: what have to be the orientation for the shell to reach some predefined point. And some points are themselves limiting cases ($d=0$) or we are considering a situation, $g=0$, that it's itself extreme: we don't consider two possible paths when gravity is zero. So, no, for $g=0$ the model is not well posed, only for values near zero.

Comment: thanks! now i get it!

Comment: And yes, as you can see maths follow your intuition... and then maths improve it!